# No Proxy Service created when using MQ Transport in oracle service bus

Tags: proxy, osb, oracle-service-bus

When I am creating a new Proxy Service using MQ transport, it only creates the Pipeline and not the actual proxy service.

This happens only with MQ transport and not with other types of adapters... The navigator in oracle service bus console is not displaying the proxy service and is only displaying the pipeline...

Comment: Can you describe more details how you create the Proxy-Service?
Currently it's hard to give you improvement-advises.

Comment: It was a crappy problem, the EndPoint URI has two extra spaces in the end... fixed now...thanks for the comment